# BrainF**k interpreter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter, brainfuck

Here's what I've come up with:

```py
def bf_interpreter(code: str) -> str:
    """
    Interprets BrainF**k code

    Examples:
        ++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
        Hello World!

        +++++>++++[<+>-]++++++++[<++++++>-]<.
        9

    """

    outputs = []

    ptr = 0

    values = [0]
    length = 1

    brackets = []

    index = 0
    code_length = len(code)

    while index < code_length:
        char = code[index]

        while length <= ptr:
            length += 1
            values.append(0)

        if char == '>': ptr += 1
        if char == '<': ptr -= 1

        if char == '+': values[ptr] = (values[ptr] + 1) % 256
        if char == '-': values[ptr] = (values[ptr] - 1) % 256

        if char == '[':
            brackets.append(index)

        if char == ']':
            if values[ptr] == 0:
                brackets.pop()
            else:
                index = brackets[-1]

        if char == '.':
            outputs.append(chr(values[ptr]))

        if char == ',':
            values[ptr] = ord(input())

        index += 1

    return ''.join(outputs)
```

How do I make this look better? (More consistent, as well as strictly following PEP 8 conventions)

Comment: Can you describe the initial intention, what are the parsing rules in your custom "interpreter" ?

Comment: @AlexV Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my question as such.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I don't quite understand what you mean by `parsing rules`. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: When `char == '['`, you're supposed to check whether the value at the pointer is zero; if it is, you need to jump to after the corresponding `]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of your `if char == '>': ptr += 1` and similar checks should use `elif` after the first check. By using `if` for all of the checks, you're forcing them all to run, even once you've found a match. This is wasteful because the checks are necessarily exclusive of each other. Once one check is true, none of the other checks can be. For example, you should have:

```
if char == '>': ptr += 1
elif char == '<': ptr -= 1

elif char == '+': values[ptr] = (values[ptr] + 1) % 256
elif char == '-': values[ptr] = (values[ptr] - 1) % 256
```

Now the checks stop once a match is found which prevents unnecessary equality checks.

---

I'd also try to break this down into a few functions to help testing. Right now, you can only test `bf_interpreter` as one whole. You could have a function that takes the current character, and the state of the program (the `brackets`, `ptr`, `outputs`...), and returns a new state. That way you can easily test for a given state if a certain command produces a correct new state.

---

I'm assuming this loop is just to add padding so you don't go off the end of the slots?:

```
while length <= ptr:
    length += 1
    values.append(0)
```

You could make that a little neater by just using math and some concatenation. You could also just get rid of `length` and use `len(values)`:

```
needed = ptr - len(values)
values += [0] * needed
```

`ptr - len(values)` calculates how many slots are needed, then `[0] * needed` produces that many `0`s, and `+=` adds them to `values`. If `needed` is negative, `[0] * needed` will produce `[]`, and essentially cause no change.

If you want to avoid the temporary list that `[0] * needed` creates, you could replace that with:

```
values += (0 for _ in range(needed))
```

Now `+=` just pulls from a generator that produces values as needed.

---

And then, just like how you don't need `length`, you don't need `code_length` either. `len(code)` is fine; `len` runs in constant time. You don't need to cache it for performance reasons.

Here's some timings to show the difference in runtime this can cause:

```
import timeit

TEST_CODE = "++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++."

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: bf_interpreter_orig(TEST_CODE), number=int(2e5))  # Two hundred thousand tests
77.3481031  # Takes 77 seconds

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: bf_interpreter_len(TEST_CODE), number=int(2e5))
88.93794809999997
```

Where `bf_interpreter_orig` is your original code, and `bf_interpreter_len` is your original code but using `len`.

Yes, there's a difference. Note though, that's a ~11 second difference across *200,000* calls. That works out to roughly 58 *microseconds per call* to the interpreting function.

Unless you're calling `bf_interpreter` hundreds of thousands of times in a tight loop, the difference is unlikely to matter. This also likely has nothing to do with the fact that you're requesting a length, and more to do with one extra function call. Function calls aren't super fast in Python. Likely any extra call to any function would have similar effects.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to use `len(values)`, but wouldn't it be more time consuming? If having a variable to calculate the length takes `4.78` seconds, using `len(values)` takes `7.549` seconds.

Comment: @Srivaths  See my edit at the bottom. The time difference isn't as big as your findings show. You're likely using too small of a sample, or a poor benchmarking method.

Comment: I did not exactly use the `bf_interpreter` function to time the difference. See https://pastebin.com/uZNR3ArW

Comment: @Srivaths When I run that exact test, I get 13.8 seconds for `code1`, and 11.2 seconds for `code2`. That's in the neighborhood of the results that I got with my full test (81% as fast for my test vs 86% as fast with your test).

Comment: Your tests seem *abnormally* slow. Do you have something running in the background that could be messing with tests?

Comment: Hmm... No, I don't think so. But maybe the IDEs make a difference. I use PyCharm.

Comment: I would find `values.extend(0 for _ in range(needed))` more readable than `values += (0 for _ in range(needed))`. As far as performance is concerned, they seem to be about equally fast (not that it would matter in this case). This whole `list` business is kinda inelegant and would be handled more nicely with `defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 6):

+1 on specifying argument `code: str` and return type `-> str`.

I implemented a class seen below which has the advantage of seeing chars and their corresponding functions at a glance. Adding new chars if need be is incredibly easy.

```py
        self.actions = {
            '>': self.greater_than,
            '<': self.less_than,
            '+': self.plus,
            '-': self.minus,
            '[': self.left_bracket,
            ']': self.right_bracket,
            '.': self.dot,
            ',': self.comma
        }
```

You can use a

```
try:
    ...
except KeyError:
    ...
```

to detect unrecognised chars.

## Complete Class

```py
class BFInterpreter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outputs = []

        self.ptr = 0

        self.values = [0]
        self.length = 1

        self.brackets = []

        self.index = 0

    def greater_than(self):
        self.ptr += 1

    def less_than(self):
        self.ptr -= 1

    def plus(self):
        self.values[self.ptr] = (self.values[self.ptr] + 1) % 256

    def minus(self):
        self.values[self.ptr] = (self.values[self.ptr] - 1) % 256

    def left_bracket(self):
        self.brackets.append(self.index)

    def right_bracket(self):
        if self.values[self.ptr] == 0:
            self.brackets.pop()
        else:
            self.index = self.brackets[-1]

    def dot(self):
        self.outputs.append(chr(self.values[self.ptr]))

    def comma(self):
        self.values[self.ptr] = ord(input())

    def evaluate(self, code):
        self.code = code
        self.code_length = len(self.code)

        self.actions = {
            '>': self.greater_than,
            '<': self.less_than,
            '+': self.plus,
            '-': self.minus,
            '[': self.left_bracket,
            ']': self.right_bracket,
            '.': self.dot,
            ',': self.comma
        }

        while self.index < self.code_length:
            char = self.code[self.index]

            while self.length <= self.ptr:
                self.length += 1
                self.values.append(0)

            self.actions[char]()

            self.index += 1

        return ''.join(self.outputs)
```

## Usage

```py
bf = BFInterpreter()
print(bf.evaluate('+++++>++++[<+>-]++++++++[<++++++>-]<.'))
```

code has been specified as an argument in the evaluate method rather than in the constructor to be able to evaluate without creating new objects.

Comment: Now change `BFInterpreter` to `BFCode(str)` and change `evaluate(self, code)` to `__call__(self)`. Boom.

Comment: _"…to be able to evaluate without creating new objects."_ And what exactly is the point of that? You cannot reuse the object after calling `evaluate` anyways. Your concept of `__init__` + `evaluate` is bad for readability and usability of your code. I would either make a wrapper method that creates a `BFInterpreter`, then calls `evaluate` on it and returns the result; or create what I call a "function-like class": a class with `__new__` method in which you create an instance, call some method(s) on it (such as `evaluate`), and return the result (instead of returning an instance of the class).

Comment: In the spirit of you once forge a spoon and use it may times, not creating a spoon each time you want to use it. You create an object then use a method many times versus creating a new instance each time you want to evaluate

Comment: Have you read and understood my comment? You _cannot_ use your instance multiple times, since you don't reset the variables `self.outputs`, `self.values`, etc. in the `evaluate` method. You could use the object multiple times if you _did_ reset those variables in the `evaluate` method, but then there would be absolutely no point in creating and reusing the object, since there would be no initialization of the object done in the constructor. You might as well change `evaluate` to a `classmethod` and create a new instance in that method.

Comment: Oh and by the way, your implementation is neither thread- nor exception-safe. It would be, however, if you did what I told you. **PS.** if you still believe that your object is reusable, just try to reuse it on these inputs: `'+++++>++++[<+>-]++++++++[<++++++>-]<.'` and `''` (an empty string). The first should (and does) print `9`; however the second should print nothing but prints `9` instead. And one more thing, your program fails for inputs  which contain other characters than the 8 control ones, which makes it neither a valid BF interpreter, nor equivalent with OP's original program.

Comment: @kyrill those comments are by far most understandable. Will amend!